# why does "jdk6/javac -cp .:dependentJarCompiledWith1.7.jar Target.java" work fine?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

I can use `javac(1.6)` to compile a class with a dependent jar that compiled with 1.7 in classpath, It just echo a warning message.

---

```
/usr/java/jdk6/bin/javac -cp .:/home/alvin/ship/b.jar a/A.java
```

> Warning: b/B.class(b:B.class):major version 51 is newer than 50 the
>   highest major version supported by this compiler

---

why does the `javac` can have the `'upward compatible'` and what is the detail?
I guess the compiler just check whether the dependent Classes and its method signature is existent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The Java® Language Specification, chapter 13](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) explains in details this aspect of Java.